# What does one mean by magnitude of normal in co-ordinate geometry?

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Basically whenever I imagine a surface, by normal at a point, I mean a straight line perpendicular to the surface at that point which has an infinite length as straight lines do have. But how does this straight line have a magnitude when I observe this from a vectorial viewpoint? Then I consider the normal to be a vector and it has a magnitude. But co-ordinate geometry is analogous to vectorial geometry. That is , I can solve co-ordinate geometry problems by vectors and vice-versa. Still this thing confuses me.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Can you give a complete citation where this term occurs? It could indeed be the length of the normal after some specified computation method, or the coordinate along the unit normal vector.

Comment: @LutzL The term "unit normal" means you divide the normal vector by its magnitude. Self sufficient statement ...isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Usually, it is understood, esp. when speaking of the normal vector field, that the normal vectors have unit length. But out of context it is difficult to say.

Comment: @Aniket It seems like just changing the picture in your mind is enough to answer this.  Instead of thinking of the normal as a line, think of it as an arrow (with finite length).  This is what most people envision.  You can also think of vectors as representations of *weighted* lines.  One way to visualize a weighted line is to think of the line as being fatter or skinnier.  Technically a line has no extent in any direction except one, but there's no way to actually visualize it like that so you might as well take advantage of the way your mind *does* visualize it.

Comment: @Bye_World Point taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight line orthogonal to a surface at a point $P$ is ,in fact, a line so it has infinite length.

But the equation of a straight line is represented, usually, as $\vec x= \vec v t +\vec v_0$, here $\vec v$ is a vector that gives the direction of the line, and this vector has a magnitude,  but this magnitude has nothing to do with a ''magnitude of the line'', an expression that has no meaning.

Note that this vector is also oriented, but the straight line is the the same for opposite oriented vectors (really for all parallel vectors), with a positive orientation that is the same of the vector.

In many application it's important to define an orientation of the normal and also to have an orienting vector that has unit magnitude, so we define a normal vector to the surface, i.e. a unitary vector that orients the orthogonal line and also fix an orientations as positive.

This is useful especially in physical application as in the definition of the [flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux) of vector field through a surface.

Comment: A couple of queries: 1)In the 3rd para, I cant understand what you mean. 2)In the 4th para, you say normal vector has been defined to serve a specific purpose. Then do you agree that the normal straight line and the normal vector are different? 3)And in the 2nd para, you write the equation of the straight line in the vector form,that is, AS A VECTOR  which contradicts your opinion (as in the 2nd query) that vectors and straight lines are different. And also $\vec x$ has magnitude.. doesn't it?

Comment: Definitely a line is not a vector. But a vector $\vec v$ gives the direction of a line and if the equation of the line is $\vec x= \vec v t +\vec v_0$ ( do you know this equation?), also its orientation in the sense that that we can define as positive oriented with respect to $v_0$ the points of the line that correspond to positive values of $t$. Note that $\vec x$ has not a defined magnitude since the parameter $t$ can have any real value.

Comment: Yeah. I know that it is the vector form of the equation of a straight line in 3D. BTW your answer is quite good. Just clarify to me one thing: $\vec x$ may not have a defined magnitude, but it has a magnitude which is a function of $t$. My question is: what is the analogy of this magnitude of a normal vector to a normal (straight line) in coordinate geometry? Is it the length? But the length of a straight line is infinite whereas magnitude of a vector is finite.

Comment: Any point on the line is identified by a value of the parameter $t$ so, given the point $P(t)$, the vector $x(t)$ is the vector from the origin $O$ and $P$, and its magnitude is the distance $OP$. So, for different points $P$ we have different distances and different magnitudes, that can be great as we want.

Comment: The magnitude of the orienting vector $v$ has nothing to do with the distance of a point of the line from the origin. The vector $v$ is parallel to the line, but does not, in general, point to a point of the line, so it  can have any magnitude.